# probability question on casting a pair of dice

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability

A pair of dice is cast until a seven appears twice or until each of a six and eight has appeared at least once. Show that the probability of the six and eight occurring before two sevens is 0.546.

An attempt made was to consider 2 cases , one in which a 7 can happen and the other in which no 7 appears. In each cases the end outcome should be 6 or 8. There has to be atleast one 8 or 6 in remaining positions.I have considered it as a random variable and sum over 1 to infinity. But the answer obtained is not the one required. Please help

The equation I arrive at is: x be the position at which we end our experiment . i.e. I have a 6,8 as sum

(x-2)(6/36)(x-1)(5/36)(25/36)^(x-3)(5/36) + (x-1)(5/36)(5/36)(25/36)(x-2)
which needs to be sum over from 1 to infinity.

Comment: It would help people understand what you need help with, and might also help you clarify your thinking, if you edited the question to show exactly what steps you took and why, including the formulas and equations you wrote. You can use MathJax to make formulas readable; see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: yes , I am sure it is for a pair of dice. I don't understand what you mean by first roll is 6-7?

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thinking about a probability question using Markov chains](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947254/thinking-about-a-probability-question-using-markov-chains)

Comment: I dont know how what is and to deal with Markov chains ?

Answer (score 1):

The probability of rolling a $6$, $7$, and $8$ in a single roll of a pair of dice is $5/36$, $6/36$, and $5/36$ respectively. Since we ignore all other outcomes, you can think of the problem as instead rolling a single $3$-sided die that yields $6$, $7$, and $8$ with probability $5/16$, $6/16$, and $5/16$ respectively.

Suppose the first roll is a $6$; this happens with probability $5/16$.

- If the next non-$6$ roll is a $7$ (which happens with probability $6/11$), then the next non-$6$ roll after that must be an $8$ (which happens with probability $5/11$).
- Otherwise the next non-$6$ roll is an $8$ (probability $5/11$).

So if the first roll is $6$, you win with probability $\frac{5}{16} (\frac{6}{11} + 1) \frac{5}{11}$.

If the first roll is $8$, you obtain the same probability as well.

If the first roll is $7$ (probability $6/16$), the next roll must be $6$ or $8$ (probability $10/16$). If this roll was $6$, then we need the next non-$6$ roll to be $8$ (probability $5/11$); similarly if this roll was $8$, then the next non-$8$ roll must be $6$ (probability $5/11$). So if the first roll is $7$ you win with probability $\frac{6}{16} \cdot \frac{10}{16} \cdot \frac{5}{11}$.

Adding up these three cases yields $4225/7744 \approx 0.546$.

Comment: Why did we ignore all other outcomes?
What I mean is that , we could also have a case such that sum is as (8,2,3,4,5,...,6) etc. with no two seven and a 6 in between 8 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

You have a Markov chain with six states:  none of $6,7,8$ has appeared, $7$ has appeared but no $6$ or $8$, one of $6$ or $8$ has appeared but no $7$, both $7$ and (one of $6$ or $8$) has appeared, two $7$s have appeared (final), a $6$ and $8$ have both appeared (final).  You can ignore all other rolls and compute the transition probabilities.  For example, from start you move to one $7$ with chance $\frac 6{16}$ because there are $6$ ways to get $7$ and $10$ ways to get $6$ or $8$ and to one of $6$ or $8$ with chance $\frac {10}{16}$.

Comment: I have done the same but not arriving at .546

Comment: The answer key could be wrong.  If you show your work we may see the error.  It is much easier to check work than to do it.